# How to best sort the corners of a rectangle without knowing the width or height?

Tags: c++, opencv, math

I have four coordinates of a detected rectangle. I want to find out which of these is the top left, top right , bottom left and bottom right points.
The method I have written myself is (unnecessarily) long and hasn't actually worked (possibly because I made a mistake somewhere). Either way I'm sure there is an easier way but I can't find a method using google. So any help would be appreciated.

My method is to find the corners with max y(most-top), min y(most-bottom), max x(most-right), min x (most-left). And then if the most-left.y > the most-right.y then the top left point is most-left, top right is most-top etc.
Is this method correct? And is there an easier way?

My code, sorry its messy and confusing... squareX[0] is first x coordinate squareY[0] is first y coordinate etc.

Edit: Turns out my method is fine its just max() doesn't do what I thought it did (return the max number out off all the numbers entered).

```
            maxx = max(squareX[0], squareX[1], squareX[2], squareX[3]);
            maxy = max(squareY[0], squareY[1], squareY[2], squareY[3]);
            minx = min(squareX[0], squareX[1], squareX[2], squareX[3]);
            miny = min(squareY[0], squareY[1], squareY[2], squareY[3]);

            if (squareX[0] == maxx)
            {
                mx = 0;
            }
            if (squareX[1] == maxx)
            {
                mx = 1;
            }
            if (squareX[2] == maxx)
            {
                mx = 2;
            }
            if (squareX[3] == maxx)
            {
                mx =3;
            }

            if (squareX[0] == minx)
            {
                mix = 0;
            }
            if (squareX[1] == minx)
            {
                mix = 1;
            }
            if (squareX[2] == minx)
            {
                mix = 2;
            }
            if (squareX[3] == minx)
            {
                mix = 3;
            }

            if (squareY[0] == maxy)
            {
                my = 0;
            }
            if (squareY[1] == maxy)
            {
                my = 1;
            }
            if (squareY[2] == maxy)
            {
                my = 2;
            }
            if (squareY[3] == maxy)
            {
                my = 3;
            }

            if (squareY[0] == miny)
            {
                miy = 0;
            }
            if (squareY[1] == miny)
            {
                miy = 1;
            }
            if (squareY[2] == miny)
            {
                miy = 2;
            }
            if (squareY[3] == miny)
            {
                miy = 3;
            }

            if (squareY[mix] > squareY[mx])
            {
                Pt1.x = squareX[mix];
                Pt1.y = squareY[mix];
                Pt2.x = squareX[my];
                Pt2.y = squareY[my];
                Pt3.x = squareX[mx];
                Pt3.y = squareY[mx];
                Pt4.x = squareX[miy];
                Pt4.y = squareY[miy];
            }
            else
            {
                Pt1.x = squareX[my];
                Pt1.y = squareY[my];
                Pt2.x = squareX[mx];
                Pt2.y = squareY[mx];
                Pt3.x = squareX[miy];
                Pt3.y = squareY[miy];
                Pt4.x = squareX[mix];
                Pt4.y = squareY[mix];
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the rectangle parallel to axes-es or not?

Comment: Your way seems to be the easiest there can be, so it's not clear what you want to simplify. So please add your code.

Comment: It can be in any orientation but probably not in parallel to the axes.

Comment: First, sort the rectangles along the starting point in the x-direction and then along y. You will end up having sorted the group.

Comment: If the rectangle can be a square and can have any orientation, how do you define the top left corner if the square is standing exactly on a tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the points by how far left they are.  The first two points are the left side of the rectangle.  Sort those two points by height.  The highest is the top left point, the other is bottom left. do the same for the two on the right.

Comment: Using lexicographical ordering (compare on X, then on Y in case of a tie) will perform both in a single go.

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to use as few comparisons as possible:

```
if X0 == X1:
  # P0 and P1 are on a vertical
  if X0 < X2:
    # P0 and P1 are on the left
  else:
    # P2 and P3 are on the left
    swap P0-P2
    swap P1-P3
else:
  # P0 and P1 are on a diagonal
  if X0 < X1:
    # P0 is on the left
    if X0 < X2:
      # P0 and P3 are on the left
      swap P1-P3
    else:
      # P0 and P2 are on the left
      swap P1-P2
  else:
    # P1 is on the left
    if X1 < X2:
      # P1 and P3 are on the left
      swap P0-P3
    else:
      # P1 and P2 are on the left
      swap P0-P2
```

After two or three comparisons on X, you have identified the pairs of left and right corners (now P0-P1 and P2-P3).

```
if Y0 > Y1:
  # P1 is upper
  swap P0-P1

if Y2 > Y3:
  # P3 is upper
  swap P2-P3
```

With two more comparisons on Y (downward increasing), the rectangle is 0231, clockwise.

You can't do that in less than 5 comparisons, because you need to cover the 24 permutations (2^4 <= 24 <= 2^5). But all swaps can be avoided by replicating the last two comparisons where necessary (six places), with appropriate renumbering.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem lately and let me share my scheme:

1. Calculate the center of your rectangle.
2. Use the center of your rectangle as the new origin for your corners.
3. Convert your corners into polar coordinates.
4. Sort the corners by its angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Standard C++ Library, `min_element` and `max_element` with a custom comparator. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) is the official documentation.

I have a simple example [here](https://github.com/nkint/OF_sketches/blob/master/boundingBox/src/testApp.cpp) (it is not pure opencv sorry but the porting is trivial).